# Please help to find the formula for a relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm trying to find the formula for the following relation:

$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n $

where:

$ 0 \leq x_1 \leq  3$

$ 0 \leq  x_2 \leq 3$

$ x_3 \geq  0 $

$ x_3 \geq  0 $

Let $a_n$ be the number of different compositions of $n$ items.

Here is the generating-function I've made for $\{a_n\}$ sequence according to the limitations:

$ (1+x+x^2+x^3)^2\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right) $

How to find the formula of $a_n$?

$ a_0 = 1 $

$ a_1 = 4 $

Regards.

Comment: Please check the question... the seems to be something missing

Comment: Now it's better?

Comment: Well... maybe we have a different understanding of *generating function*, but to me the one you wrote makes no sense.

Comment: Instead of $n$, should the right side be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$?

Comment: I've made some editing, hope now it's looking better. Sorry everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Your generating function is correct.  Here is the Mathematica code for the Taylor series expansion about x=0 of your g.f.: nn = 20; CoefficientList[Series[((1 - x^4)/(1 - x))^2/(1 - x)^2, {x, 0, nn}], x].  It returns: 1, 4, 10, 20, 33, 48, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 144, 160, 176, 192, 208,224, 240, 256, 272, 288,...

You can see the terms are increasing by 16 after n=5 (which makes sense because for n>=6 we have run through the cases dictated by the first two summands).

The formula is (for n>=5), a(n)= 16*n - 32.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain a bit how did you get from the generating function to the formula? I can't track the steps...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that
the desired relation is
$(1+x+x^2+x^3)^2(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2})
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n
&=(1+x+x^2+x^3)^2(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2})\\
&=(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x})^2(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2})\\
&=\frac{(1-x^4)^2}{(1-x)^4}\\
&=(1-x^4)^2(1-x)^{-4}\\
&=(1-x^4)^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-4}{n}(-1)^n x^n\\
&=(1-x^4)^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\binom{n+3}{3}(-1)^n x^n\\
&=(1-2x^4+x^8)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+3}{3} x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+3}{3} x^n
-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+3}{3} x^{n+4}
+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+3}{3} x^{n+8}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+3}{3} x^n
-2\sum_{n=4}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{3} x^{n}
+\sum_{n=8}^{\infty} \binom{n-5}{3} x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{7} \binom{n+3}{3} x^n
-2\sum_{n=4}^{7} \binom{n-1}{3} x^{n}
+\sum_{n=8}^{\infty} (\binom{n+3}{3}-2\binom{n-1}{3}+\binom{n-5}{3}) x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{3} \binom{n+3}{3} x^n
+\sum_{n=4}^{7} (\binom{n+3}{3}-2\binom{n-1}{3}) x^{n}
+\sum_{n=8}^{\infty} (\binom{n+3}{3}-2\binom{n-1}{3}+\binom{n-5}{3}) x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

This gives all values of $a_n$.
The expressions for
$a_n$ for
$n \ge 8$
can be simplified,
because the
$n^3$ and, possibly,
the $n^2$ will drop out.

Comment: Thanks! I need an expression for $a_n$ such that when I plug a number in place of $n$ it will produce me be the number of different compositions of $n$ items.

Comment: Just do a search for "number of compositions". Here is the first hit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)